# How to concurrently modify a Vector

Tags: java, vector, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

I have to ensure while iterating the Vector; there is no update on that Vector to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`. I can use concurrent collection. But i just want to give a try on Vector. Below is the code I have written.

```
public class TestConcurrentModification1 {
    Vector a = new Vector();

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final TestConcurrentModification1 obj = new TestConcurrentModification1();

        new Thread(){
            public  void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    obj.a.add(""+i);                
                }
                System.out.println(obj.a);
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread(){
            public  void run(){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                synchronized (obj.a) {
                    Iterator itr = obj.a.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()) {
                        obj.a.add("TEST");//java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
                        //itr.remove(); //java.lang.IllegalStateException
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

But the above code is throwing 1) `OutOfMemoryError` OR  2) `IllegalStateException`. Could you please explain what is causing these two exception. And how to achieve my goal of avoiding `ConcurrentModificationException` on a `Vector`?

I have to solve this for Java 1.4.2 or prior.

Comment: Do not use `Vector`. Instead, choose a proper class from `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` is not necessarily for concurrent as in multi-`Thread`ed. You cannot add/remove from a collection while iterating over it. You can remove if you use the `Iterator` itself.

Comment: Also, pay a good read on this Q/A: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks. But I even mentioned that i want to try with Vector.

Comment: And we stand for **you should not use it**.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks! I didn't get your comment clearly! Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza :) Ok tell me how it is handled before Java5

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169913/avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-on-list-by-making-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: Team, Thanks for your comments. Could you please also tell me the root cause for those two exceptions/Error in my code ??

Comment: Every time you add an element, your iterator `next()` will find a new element and loop again. To infinity and beyond!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  It is happening for only 10 elements also. I updated my for loop length from 100 to 10. Still error is coming.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Imagine a vector with one element: `if (it.hasNext())` => true `a.add("");` (now the vector has two elements) => `if (it.hasNext())` => true `a.add("")` (now the vector has three elements) etc. That's what your loop is doing...

Comment: @assylias Thanks for your response. But this happens for even with for loop of 2 elements :(

Comment: if i comment out that line "obj.a.add("TEST");" my program is never ending...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The above code is very fine which will avoid ConcurrentModificationException while removing.. only i missed .next()...  For Adding i should come out from iteration then do add()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of your Problem:

```
 Iterator itr = obj.a.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()) {
     obj.a.add("TEST");// <- if itr.hasNext() would have returned false in next iteration, now it won't
 }
```

This is an **infinite loop** that increases memory usage in each iteration. So you'll run into an OutOfMemory sooner or later.

I suggest using a good old for-loop for inserting values. Use an iterator if you actually want to *iterate* something :)

More: You are synchronizing against a non-final member.

More: Iterator.remove throws ...

> IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method.

And last but not least: The race condition already mentioned by Sotirios (+1 for him).
Whenever you synchronize, make sure you synchronize every call on the critical resource.

Comment: No if i comment out that line "obj.a.add("TEST");" my program is never ending... Problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Of course it does not, because your iterator never advances! "HasNext" does not change the iterator's position. You have to call `next` inside the loop.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar Note that if you call `next()`, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Note that for your last point, `Vector` is already `synchronized` on all (most?) the `public` methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That, of course, is true. Just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good old race condition on your hands.

Your first `Thread`, except for adding the first element to your `Vector`, serves absolutely no purpose. You can replace it with

```
obj.a.add("first");
```

The beef, as others have noted, is here

```
Iterator itr = obj.a.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    obj.a.add("TEST");// java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
    // heap space
    // itr.remove(); //java.lang.IllegalStateException
}
```

`itr.hasNext()` is implemented as

```
public boolean hasNext() {           
    return cursor != elementCount;
}
```

Where cursor starts at `0` and `elementCount` is the size of your `Vector`. **This call will never return `false`.** Your `while` loop with loop, adding elements, until the program runs out of memory. The `cursor` never moves forward because you never call `next()`. If you do call `next()` while adding elements directly to the `Vector`, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.